# In Notepad++, how can I launch the current html file as url?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I have a `js` file which runs node server code. ( via `notepad++` using `NPPExec`)

[image]

Ok - So now the server is up and listening at `http://localhost:3030`

However , I have a left pane of explorer tree :

[image]

Goal :

- Take the current file name
- Calc its relative location to `c:\program Files (x86)\nodejs\public folder`
- Prepend  `http://localhost:3030`
- run `chrome.exe "http://localhost:3030/" + "/angularjs-book-master/chapter2/amail/index.html"`

So , I want to run this :

`NPP_RUN chrome.exe http://localhost:3030/(current file relative to nodejs`public`folder)`

**Notice : I want to run it as a url**.

So in my example I want :

`NPP_RUN chrome.exe http://localhost:3030/angularjs-book-master/chapter2/amail/index.html`

Where `index.html` is the current displayed file.

But the problem is that I don't have merely `/angularjs-book-master/chapter2/amail/index.html`

I have the *full* value which is `$(FILE_NAME)` which is

`file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/nodejs/public/angularjs-book-master/chapter1/order-form.html`

And I don't need this whole string. A solution which will cut `file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/nodejs/public/` from it would also be fine.

Also the slashed should be backwards.

**so in short :**

I have `NPP_RUN "chrome.exe" $(FILE_NAME)`

But this runs :

`chrome.exe file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/nodejs/public/angularjs-book-master/chapter2/amail/index.html`

But I want **only** this : (notice slashes)

`chrome.exe http://localhost:3030/angularjs-book-master/chapter2/amail/index.html`

Comment: found it. read about `set <var> ~ strreplace`